# Convert CSV to List<List<dynamic>> with rows and columns

Tags: list, flutter, csv, file

I want to convert csv to List<List> my code bellow is working and get the file and convert it like this:
[[item 1;1200;1300],[item 2;1200;1300]].

It's handle [item 1;1200;1300] as a single element I can't reach item 1 or 1200 or 1300 as alone.

I want to handle it like this List[0][0] the result will be item 1.

```
TextButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
                    type: FileType.custom,
                    allowedExtensions: ['csv'],
                    dialogTitle: 'Choose Your File',
                  );
                  if (result != null) {
                    PlatformFile file = result!.files.first;
                    filePath = file.path!;
                    prvdr.openFile(filePath);
                  } else {}
                },
                child: const Text('Press Here'),
              ),
```

The Fuction

```
void openFile(filePath) async {
    File itemsFile = File(filePath);
    print('CSV to List');
    final input = itemsFile.openRead();
    final fields = await input.transform(utf8.decoder).transform(const CsvToListConverter()).toList();
    print(fields);
    for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
      print(fields[i][0]);
      print(fields[i][1]);
      print(fields[i][2]);
    }
  }
```

My csv is like this

```
item 1;1200;1300
item 2;1200;1300
item 3;1200;1300
item 4;1200;1300
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do a for loop that loops on the list and splits every element by ;

Example:

```
final fields = await input.transform(utf8.decoder).transform(const CsvToListConverter()).toList();
List<List<String>> finalList = [];

for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
  finalList.add(fields[i].split(";"));
}

// Now you cand access finalList
for(var i = 0; i < finalFields.length; i++){
  print(finalFields[i][0]);
  print(finalFields[i][1]);
  print(finalFields[i][2]);
}
```

Comment: I solved it, thank you for your time by the way your solution work, thanks.

Comment: Most welcome, feel free to upvote the answer if you think it was helpful